# What is our stance on questions “looking for exercises to learn statistical concept X with library Y”?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

What is our stance on questions “looking for exercises to learn statistical concept X with library Y”? Are they on-topic or off-topic?

Example: [Exercises to learn neural network with Tensorflow](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/277957/12359):

> I am a new user, fan of neural network. I took the course : https://www.udemy.com/data-science-deep-learning-in-python/. For me, the best way to learn something is to make some exercises. So I would like to practice neural network. Furthermore, I would like to use Tensorflow to make those exercises. Could anyone be able to suggest some great, easy exercises in this domain? In fact, I am interested by great website or tutorial, but the only thing I want is to practice. I want clear questions and features provide to complete the exercises.

Answer (score 6):

Questions asking for references to learn statistical concept X are on-topic (this has been decided sometime in the past). One efficient way to learn certain statistical concepts is to do exercises, sometimes coding exercises, potentially using some specific library or programming language. Therefore I believe questions looking for exercises to learn statistical concept X with library Y should be on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I think that we should interpret this carefully and conservatively. The quoted snippet is typical of the "developer" mindset, focused entirely on a narrow praxis and largely ignorant of theory. Considering the many risks of naively and improperly applied mathematical practices to the field of statistics, it seems appropriate to make sure that people aren't just learning to operate a (possibly dangerous) machine, but also to understand why it does what it does.

If the question asks about theory or theory-aware practice, I think it's on topic. If someone has no interest in the difference between ["lies, damned lies, and statistics"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lies,_damned_lies,_and_statistics) and just wants to learn to write code, then I suppose it's off to Stack Overflow with them.